# Return count from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `ArrayList` that stores an inventory of cars. I want the user to input start year and end year and return a number of cars in inventory in the year range specified. I have to use a foreach loop and get all the years to display. How can I count them? Below is what I have so far

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear)
{
   int totalYear = 0;
   for(Lamborghini year : inventory)
   { 
      if((year.getModelYear() >= startYear)
            && (year.getModelYear() <= endYear)) {
        totalYear = year.getModelYear();
        System.out.println(totalYear);   
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close. Increment `totalYear` and `return` it. Something like,

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear) {
    int totalYear = 0;
    for (Lamborghini year : inventory) {
        int modelYear = year.getModelYear();
        if ((modelYear >= startYear) && (modelYear <= endYear)) {
            totalYear++;
            System.out.printf("modelYear: %d, total: %d%n", modelYear, 
                    totalYear);
        }
    }
    return totalYear;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to count, you should increase `totalYear` by 1 for each car with a desired `modelYear`. I.e., change `totalYear = year.getModelYear();` to

```
totalYear++;
```

BTW, if you are using Java 8, you may want to use lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Java 8 constructs, another approach you could use is streams and predicates. You can get a stream view of the ArrayList, apply a predicate to it, and then get the count:

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear) {
    return inventory.stream()
        .filter((Lamborghini year) -> (modelYear >= startYear) && (modelYear <= endYear))
        .count();
}
```

What this does is get a set of Lamborghini objects from the inventory that match your condition via the `filter` method, and then return the count of how many items matched.